# Alternativa String.replace()

Tags: java, desempenho

Estou com uma pulga atrás da orelha.

Tenho um método que remove / altera alguns caracteres da string, é algo desse tipo :

```
public static String replaceCharSet(String texto) {
    texto = texto.replace("&", "E");
    texto = texto.replace("$", "S");
    texto = texto.replace("á", "a");
    ................
    return texto;
}
```

Bom isso se repete por varias e varias linhas e além de causar uma perca no desempenho estou desconfiado de memory leak.

Existe alguma forma mais elegante / funcional de fazer isso ?

Segue a lista de todos os caracteres que preciso editar/modificar :

```
"&", "E"
"$", "S"
"ç", "c"
"Ç", "C"
"á", "a"
"Á", "A"
"à", "a"
"À", "A"
"ã", "a"
"Ã", "A"
"â", "a"
"Â", "A"
"ä", "a"
"Ä", "A"
"é", "e"
"É", "E"
"è", "e"
"È", "E"
"ê", "e"
"Ê", "E"
"ë", "e"
"Ë", "E"
"í", "i"
"Í", "I"
"ì", "i"
"Ì", "I"
"î", "i"
"Î", "I"
"ï", "i"
"Ï", "I"
"ó", "o"
"Ó", "O"
"ò", "o"
"Ò", "O"
"õ", "o"
"Õ", "O"
"ô", "o"
"Ô", "O"
"ö", "o"
"Ö", "O"
"ú", "u"
"Ú", "U"
"ù", "u"
"Ù", "U"
"û", "u"
"Û", "U"
"ü", "u"
"Ü", "U"
"º", "o"
"ª", "a"
"-", " "
".", " "
```

> Utilizo JAVA 8, impossibilitado de migrar no momento para outras versões. É um código antigo aqui da empresa que pretendo melhorar.

Comment: Já tentou fazer uma regex? Quais outros itens você precisa substituir alem dos 3 citados?

Comment: Não tentei/pensei ainda nessa possibilidade. Preciso remover/alterar diversos outros caracteres "especiais" exemplo : ö > o , ª > a , nunca faço algo do tipo á > vazio , pois preciso da string completa só que com eles modificados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basicamente precisa trocar caracteres acentuados por não acentuados a classe [Normalizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) parece uma boa opção ela faz decomposição dos caracteres baseado no código UTF-8 e esse comportamento varia de acordo com a forma escolhida.

Como existem quatro exceções fiz um replace para cada já que `$` não será convertido para `S`, nem `&` para `E`. Pode organizar elas como um enum na sua classe.

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class t {

    String entrada = "olá mundo? é ª º 123 ? $ & * ., x";

    entrada = entrada.replace('$', 'S')
                     .replace('&', 'E')
                     .replace('-', ' ')
                     .replace('.', ' ');

    String saida = Normalizer.normalize(entrada, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
    System.out.println(saida.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""));
}
```

Saída:

```
ola mundo? e a o 123 ? S E *  , x
```

**Baseado em:**

[Easy way to remove UTF-8 accents from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15190656/1342547)

[Unicode Normalization Forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/)

[Unicode Normalization](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/uc/nfc_vs_nfd.html)

Comment: Encontrei um probleminha, alguns caracteres permanecem por fazer parte do UTF-8 exemplo : $ - & e preciso remove-los

Comment: @MateusVeloso `, .` também precisam ser removidos?

Comment: Apenas o  "  .  " por " " , ao menos é o que temos em código aqui, ai preciso algo que me traga o mesmo retorno porque é usado em todo sistema

Comment: @MateusVeloso alterei a resposta.